# using JSF PrimeFaces' text editor, how to add text in PDF using iText

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, itext

We are using JSF PrimeFaces' text editor. When we receive String from text editor in backing bean, it also includes HTML tags. Following image might help in understanding this problem.

Following is what we wrote:

[image]

Following is what we received:

[image]

Next thing we want to do is, to write what was written in text editor, as it is, into PDF using iText. But we do not know how to convert this string (with HTML tags) into only data.

Following was the code:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go for `XMLWorker` in iText. Below code will give you the content in Orange color

```
document.open();
String finall=  "<style>h1{color:orange;} </style><body><h1>This is a Demo</h1></body>";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(finall.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter,document, is);
document.close();
```

Whatever `HTML` content we are giving it will create it as `PDF`. The only thing to take care is it will work for `XHTML` means all the opening tags should have a end tag.
For example in HTML for break we will use `<br>` but here it should be `<br/>`Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice answer there Sathesh S :)

Comment: thank you so much, it worked....
http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker
follow this link to download XMLWorkerHelper's library (.jar file)

Comment: @Asadullah One thing to keep in mind that iText version 5 is not open source anymore. Its under difference license ,if you deploy your application outside your internal network you'll have to pay for license or use older version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSoup` to achieve this. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Then in your `code`

```
Jsoup.parse(textRecievedFromEditor).text();
```

This will return text without HTML Tags.

```
e.g.

For example, given HTML {@code <p>Hello <b>there</b> now!</p>}, 
{@code p.text()} returns {@code "Hello there now!"}
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply.
you see, we do want to get text, but write it as it is into PDF, by which i mean to say that, bold thing should be bold while writing into PDF. Italic, Font, Colour etc should get written as they were in text editor.

Comment: What version of iText you're using ??

Comment: the version is, itext-5.4.5